How to bring back clickable Google map in Google search results?
Recently Google made a really terrible change of not allowing the user to click the map in search results, who knows why. It normally opened Google Maps with the given location. I heard it's related to some EU changes and the problem exists only in Europe.
I accepted some Google popup asking for permission to enable cross-service integrations or something like that. But that changed nothing.
Now I also noticed on another account from the same country - Poland - that it is working there in the same browser. So I must be missing some Google permission or switch that wasn't turned on.
Does anyone have a workaround for this? It's doable with userscript of course, which I might write if no alternative appear, but I'd prefer a quicker and Google-based solution that works in all browsers where I'm logged in, if possible.

Maybe not the solution you wanted but I created a Chrome extension, Google Maps QuickClick - Search to Maps, that fixes this and returns clickable map images to the search page.

Instantly open Google Maps from Search page by clicking on a map image
or the new button.
Revive the ease of direct Google Maps access with this simple
extension.
Click on any static map in your search results to open Google Maps
instantly or enjoy the convenience of an 'Open Google Maps' button
embedded within all interactive map results.

Works reliably for all location searches, even those with incomplete or misspelled addresses
Google Maps opens to the correct location as shown in static map images
Accurately handles searches for distant locations, ensuring the correct place is shown on Google Maps
Supports scenarios with multiple map images on a search results page, making each one clickable and accurately linked to its
respective location
Supports dark mode



Thanks, I've seen that one. Doesn't meet my criteria of being readily available in all browsers, but could be useful for someone else.

this extension is great, could you port it to an Opera browser extension? I'm getting ready to dump chrome soon

@Vland Chrome extensions can be easily installed in Opera the same way as in Chrome.

@Destroy666 ok thanks, I managed to copy the folder and install it manually. gj

You don't need to copy anything. You just enter that link with Opera and press a button. It says "Add to Chrome" but it installs it to current Chromium-based browser.

oh ok, great. that's even easier

You can use the Google Search Maps Button Chrome extension. It makes the search result map images clickable again.
